# Можно ли отследить событие вызова Skype и/или любого SIP-клиента?

Tags: c++, winapi

**Есть ли способ отследить событие звонка Skype из своего приложения?**

Не требуется ничего перехватывать, расшифровывать и делать прочие гадости - просто сам факт, чтобы например освободить камеру (а потом включить по завершению вызова), или не выполнять каких-либо других действий, которые могут помешать разговору. Также данный вопрос интересует по SIP-клиентам, например Zoiper...

Comment: у скайпа есть desktop api, которое позволяет к нему подключиться и получать события: сообщения, вызовы.

Comment: Интересно. Изучу этот вопрос... Спасибо за совет. Но может есть более общие события, например сетевые, не привязанные к API и специфичные именно для вызовов IP-телефонии?

Comment: Да, по сетевому трафику будет проще: за sip закреплены конкретные порты, используя rav сокеты можно прослушать трафик.